# LinkageError while starting tomcat from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gradle, slf4j

I am trying to get a tomcat running in eclipse in the server-view.

my project setup:

```
-subproject
  -src/main/java
     {mycode}
  -build.gradle
-webappproject
  -src/main/java
     {mycode}
  -build.gradle
-build.gradle
```

The webapp project depends on the subproject.
I add the webapp-project to my server in the server-view. The server starts up fine. When I open one of my pages (where I use one of the classes from the subproject) I get a class not found exception.

To fix this, I added a the subroject to the user-entries in the classpath of the server-run-coniguration. When i was still developing on linux, this fixed the problem and everything was fine.

Now I am working on Windows 8 and get this exception during startup of the tomcat.

```
Jun 12, 2014 4:57:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception starting filter WicketApplication
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type LoggerFactory; used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:306)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.<clinit>(WicketFilter.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5485)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If i build the war and put it in tomcat/webapps it works.

my build.gradle contains

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

Please help me out here.

Comment: Also, I think this can happen if you marked slf4j logger as compile rather than provided when you deploy it. E.g. in this article: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/253499/java-lang-linkageerror-loader-constraint-violation-for-logger

Comment: I have marked slf4j-api as a compile dependecy in the subproject. Reason is that I want logging for another application that depends on the subproject that does not run inside tomcat and therefore needs it's own logging. Does tomcat provide it's own slf4j-api? I can't find it in apache/libs. If so it would indeed make sense to change the dependency to provided.

Comment: @phil_20686: I went ahead and just ried it and ... it works! I can run the webapp inside eclipse! But if i build the war and put in omcat/webapps it get a ClassNotFoundException for org.slf4j.Logger as i expected. If you also figure out how to make the slf4j-api.jar appear in the .war, the bounty is yours!

Comment: I don't know much about tomcat specifically, but usually there is a folder in the server where you can deploy libraries and they get deployed at the application level, rather than at the WAR level, and you should do that for any library used by multiple wars. Disclaimer - I am in no way an expert on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know exaclty whats wrong but I have found a workaround. As phil_20686 noted the problem is that slf4j-api lies in the eclipse-classpath under WebAppLibraries. For some reason, this breaks the build. So it needs to be removed from there.

```
    eclipseClasspath{
      plusConfigurations.each{
        it.allDependencies.each{ it.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api' }
      }
    }
```

as found in [Need to exclude a dependency from eclipse using a gradle build file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571270/need-to-exclude-a-dependency-from-eclipse-using-a-gradle-build-file)

That guy was also excluding a slf4j-jar so it's probably related to my problem in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you applying `eclipse-wtp` plugin to your Gradle projects using `java` and `war` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following article very helpful in understanding this type of error:

http://frankkieviet.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/javalanglinkageerror-loader-constraint.html

Basically, what can sometimes happen is that a class loader can either try to load the class itself, or delegate to its parent loader, and so if you have a class which is self loading, and it loads the class, then the class is in the network of class loaders, but is not accessible to the parent, so if you then try to load it from another class, you are violating the constraint, as the class is already loaded, but not in a loader that the other class gets access to. At least I think thats what happens. I am looking into linkage errors in a jboss context.

Basically, the rule of thumb is that if you had a self first WAR and a parent first war that both try to load the same class, you can have a problem.